# How to separate columns in Powershell when exported to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0, export-to-csv

Pretty new in PowerShell scripting, just wanted to ask how to achieve separated columns for my query below. Since currently all columns returned by the query is placed under one column when exported to csv file.

```
$QueryPath="\\fbrwnutap05\c$\DBA\Extended Events SQL DM\UAT\SQLDM_ExtendedEvent_UAT.sql"
$OutputFile= "\\FBRWNUTAP05\c$\DBA\SSRS\ExtEvent\QueryOutput_UAT.csv"

$ExecuteQuery= Get-Content -path $QueryPath | out-string

$OutputFile

FOREACH($server in GC "\\fbrwnutap05\c$\DBA\SSRS\ExtEvent\ServerList.txt")
{

invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -query $ExecuteQuery -querytimeout 60000 | ft -autosize | out-string -width 4096 >> $OutputFile 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -query $ExecuteQuery -querytimeout 60000 | export-csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation -append
```

Comment: When exporting to a csv the `| ft -autosize` is superfluous.